# How to create a log file for a python code?

Tags: python, exception, runtime-error, logfile, error-log

How to create a log file for a python code ?
I have created an .exe file of a python code I need to save the exceptions into a separate log file.

Comment: Check the logging module https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html Particularly to https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the logging module in python for this. This helps you to log the timestamp along with the log message.

```
import logging
LOG_FILENAME = 'exception.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.ERROR)

logging.error('This message should go to the log file')
```

Comment: ooh okay 
let me try this approach 
thank you @saranya Sridharan

Comment: Welcome Priyanka :)